# How to create a wordpress widget that dynamically changes according to the page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating a plugin in which my custom sidebar widget changes content depending on the page it is loading on. One way to do this is

```
// Register and load the widget
function custom_register_widget() {
    register_widget( 'custom_widget' );
}

//trigger on every sidebar load
add_action('dynamic_sidebar', 'custom_register_widget' );
```

However, this calls the **register_widget()** on every page load ( thereby making changes to WordPress DB ), thus slowing the page speed.

Is there an efficient way to this?

Comment: You can put the add_action inside an if to check for the page you want it to be triggered on. There are multiple ways you can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer received at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/320295/how-to-create-a-wordpress-widget-that-dynamically-changes-according-to-the-page

`register_widget()` doesn't make any changes to the database. All it does is make a particular widget available to be used. It shouldn't be used on the `dynamic_sidebar` hook. It's supposed to be used on the `widgets_init` hook.